# How can I pass touch events to underlying components with Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-touch-event

I'm looking to create a debug feature. Here's a simplified representation:

```
@Composable
fun DebugLogOverlay(logs: List<String>){  
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                color = Colors.White.copy(alpha = 0.3F)
            )
    ){
        items(logs){ log ->
            ListItem(
                text = { Text(log) }
            )
        }
    }  
}
```

The goal is to overlay but not interfere with the app. Is there a way to do this? I'm looking for something similar to Flutter's IgnorePointer, but with Compose? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pointerInteropFilter` to pass `MotionEvent`s down when you return false in `onTouchEvent`. This should allow you to add an overlay without interfering with the underlying touch events.

Here's how to include it in your code:

```
// Opt in for experimental api is required as of version 1.5.4 of Compose UI
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun DebugLogOverlay(logs: List<String>){  
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(
                color = Colors.White.copy(alpha = 0.3F)
            )
            // --> Add pointerInteropFilter <--
            .pointerInteropFilter {
                // Return false here to pass down the MotionEvent
                return@pointerInteropFilter false
            },
    ){
        items(logs){ log ->
            ListItem(
                text = { Text(log) }
            )
        }
    }  
}
```